# Private IP connection Cloud SQL Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, vpc-peering

In the google cloud docs it is clearly stated that connectivity to Cloud SQL using private IP can be established across regions, however it's not what I see at the moment.
private access was enabled, but I still cannot connect to the instance in the West1 region.
Firewall rules are the same for both regions. Routes for peering networks are autocreated but have different descriptions:

1. cloudsql-postgres-googleapis-com
2. servicenetworking-googleapis-com

And have different corresponding *next hops*, which I didn't see stated anywhere in the docs as well.
Can someone shed some light on this issue?

[image]

Firewalls out are enabled for all the destinations.

[image]

First one connects fine:

[image]

Second one timeouts (in a different region):

[image]

Reproduced the same behavior on the empty project with newly created VPC.

**Update**

I tried the experiment with other service which requires private service access:
*MemoryStore with Redis* but for this services it is clearly stated that client must be in the same region as the instance to call it, so should I presume it is a typo in the Cloud Sql documentation?

[image]

MemoryStore doc:

[image]

**Update**

I found the contradiction in the google docs for Cloud SQL, the direct specific documentation for Cloud SQL and the generic documentation about private service access, can someone confirm which option is valid?

[image]

Here it says otherwise:

[image]

Link 1: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options#example

Link 2: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip#quick-reference

Comment: Is you cluster VPC native? please perform the following test Create a GCE VM on the zone West 3 in the same subnetwork as your Kube cluster and Cloud SQL instance and try to reach both instances, this is to discard issues with VPC and Cloud SQL

Comment: Update the question: created vm same zone, create two cloud SQL instances, the issue persists.

Comment: Can you please provide the two document links, typically you will find a date at the end of the documents that will tell you the latest update. However I would like to confirm and let you know which statement is true.

Comment: Hi, added links

Answer (score 1):

This [document on private access options state](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options#example_3) that " VM instances in the customer's network **can access service resources in any region** **if** the **service supports it**. ***Some services might not support cross-region communication***. For example, VM instances can only communicate with Cloud SQL instances that are in the same region. View the relevant service's documentation for more information."

Seems like it clear that all though accessing resources cross region is possible but its solely depends on specific **Service**, which implies that there are services that will not be access from different region. Seems like Cloud SQL is one such product.

The [second link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip#quick-reference) you have shared confirms it saying "You can connect through private IP across regions".

Just trying to see the contradiction here, but I don't see that. Documentation seems ok to me.